# Disable default Navigation - Previous and Next

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to disable the Next and Previous buttons on the Sales Order screen?
I was able to change the Visibility of the First and Last buttons under the DataSource but can't find the Next and Previous button:

[image: enter image description here NO!!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to the other answer is to set the Actions in a graph extension:

```
// Hide
Base.Next.SetVisible(false);
Base.Previous.SetVisible(false);
```

or

```
// Disable but visible
Base.Next.SetEnabled(false);
Base.Previous.SetEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

IN the customization project edit the ASPX and add the Next and Previous buttons:

```
<px:PXDSCallbackCommand Visible="False" Name="Last" PostData="Self" ></px:PXDSCallbackCommand>
<px:PXDSCallbackCommand Visible="False" Name="Previous" PostData="Self" ></px:PXDSCallbackCommand>
```